# Neutrino cc interaction potential calculation field theoretically

Tags: particle-physics

Is there any very good reference where neutrino charge current interaction potential is calculated field theoretically in details ?

Answer (score 1):

This book http://books.google.com/books/about/Massive_Neutrinos_in_Physics_and_Astroph.html?id=Q6pfFwIZcPgC&source=kp_cover written by mohapatra and pal is good. The calculations are not fully detailed but you can find hints on how to compute the potential.